# Add automatic page numbers in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, odt

How can I add an automatic page number to all pages in a LibreOffice .odt file?

I've already tried the following:

- Insert > Header > (name of page style)
- and Insert > Footer > (name of page style)

to add a header or footer to all pages with the current page style.

However if I do this only the first page will have a page number. The second for example doesn't have any numeration. The number seems to be set manually per page.

Any ideas? I want to make something like auto page number and every page gets a number automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From LibreOffice [help](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Inserting_Page_Numbers_in_Footers):

> ### To Insert a Page Number
>
> 1. Choose **Insert - Footer** and select the page style that you want to add the footer to.
> 2. Choose **Insert - Fields - Page Number**.
>
> ---
>
> ### To Additionally Add a Page Count
>
> 1. Click in front of the page number field, type Page and enter a space; click after the field, enter a space and then type of and enter another space.
> 2. Choose **Insert - Fields - Page Count**.

This was solved. Thanks.