# Add automatic page numbers in LibreOffice for pdf files

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I saw that you can add automatic page numbers in LibreOffice [for odt files](https://superuser.com/questions/277878/add-automatic-page-numbers-in-libreoffice) (regular docs). However I am trying to do it for PDF files.

I've already tried the following:

- Insert > Field > Slide Number

However it only does it for the first "slide" and it doesn't do it automatically at the bottom of the page.

**How can I insert page number at the bottom of each page/slide all at once?**

---

i use libreoffice draw version 7.3.4.2, as it the program that can edit PDF's

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share what application you are using in LibreOffice. I assume it is **Impress**, since you mentioned slides. But it works similarly with *Writer*.

Like shown in the screenshot below from the main menu use:

Insert > Header and Footer...

and **Apply to All**

[image]

### Edit:

Using **Draw** there is no Header/Footer main menu item. But you can use

View > Master

and insert a field e.g. page number for your needs (Insert menu) like shown below. Go back to normal view.

[image]

Page numbers are apparently not displayed at the top, hidden by other objects (in the absence of transparency). The page numbers cannot be placed at the top either.

The only solution I can see at the moment is:

- leave a free space for the page number at the desired position in all slides OR
- enlarge the drawing area slightly at the bottom (or reduce the page margin at the bottom) and place the page number there in the master.

If necessary, the text size of the page number can be adjusted.

Format > Text > Decrease Size

Comment: it seems like there is some sort of object in all the pages that obscures the page number, I tired to bring the page number to the front but this didnt work, only can see if I delete this object manualy, any help?

Comment: @moshevi - see my edit.